# Correspondence between prime ideals and Galois orbits of affine points on an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

In notes of prof. W.Stein -  http://wstein.org/edu/2010/581b/stein-algebraic_number_theory.pdf - the first paragraph of page 112 has the following told:

"When $K$ is a perfect field, the prime ideals correspond to the Galois orbits of affine points of $E(\bar{K})$."

I would be thankful if someone could elaborate what is meant here by the Galois orbits of points of $E$ and what is the implied correspondence.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the Nullstellensatz?

Comment: Yes. Here, I fail to see what is the Galois group whose action on $E(\bar{K})$ the term "galois orbit" suggests; it doesn't seem to be the Gal(K(x, y)/K(x)).

Comment: It is the Galois group of $\overline{K}$ over $K$! Note that since $E$ is defined over $K$, there is an action of this Galois group on $E(\overline{K})$.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to think a bit then; wll ask here again if I won't manage to clarify the rest by myself.

Comment: Sounds good. Perhaps you'd like to take a look at the first chapter of Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*.

Comment: After some thought I realized it is trivial (basically, correspondence between prime ideals and irreducible algebraic sets). Thank you anyway.

Comment: P.S. I do not mind if the question gets deleted.

Comment: You're welcome anyway. The right thing to do in this situation would be to answer your own question and accept the answer, so that other users can benefit from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $K = \bar{K}$, the correspondence defined by $P \mapsto \{r \in R: r(P) = 0\}$ is the well-known bijection (as follows from the Nullstellensatz, prime ideals correspond to irreducible algebraic sets), while when $K \neq \bar{K}$, any $\sigma(P)$ gets mapped to the same prime ideal when $\sigma$ runs through $Gal(\bar{K}/K)$.